# Msal Angular is not using existing tokens on session storage

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

For context, we have 2 applications. App1 is made in AngularJS/ASP.net MVC. App2 is made in pure ASP.net MVC. We are working on merging both of them into one SPA using Angular. But due to time and resource constraints, we can only upgrade App2. So for the meantime, we will be hosting both the current App1 build and the upgraded App2 on a single webserver and using only one domain.

We were able to make it work by hosting the App1 on [www.app1.com](http://www.app1.com) and App2 will be accessed on [www.app1.com/app2](http://www.app1.com/app2).

Now for the problem. What happens is that when App2 is accessed, MSAL will then re-authenticate the user and store the tokens on the browser session storage and then redirects back to the homepage (App1). When you try to access again App2, it will still re-authenticate and goes back to the homepage. But if you will check the application's session storage on the browser, there are already tokens on the session storage which grows every time App2 is being accessed.

Is there a way to make MSAL detect the tokens already existing on the session storage? Or is our current setup even possible?

Comment: Single Sign on between multiple clients depends on the application(client) environment and authentication flow.SSO through the browser. This is achieved using browser cookies and is controlled by the server (AAD). For best experience, you need to use a system browser.

Answer (score 0):

Single Sign on between multiple clients depends on the application(client) environment and authentication flow.SSO through the browser. This is achieved using browser cookies and is controlled by the server (AAD). For best experience, you need to use a system browser.